# determining which hours in multiple days have non-NA values

Tags: r

I have a data frame with three columns: DATE, HOUR, HRC
(So there are 24 rows for each DATE)
The HRC column is sometimes a number and sometimes NA.
I am trying to figure out a way of taking a subset of DATEs and then figuring out the HOURs that have non-NA values across all days.

Example: so if DATES are Aug16, Aug18, Aug19, and HRC column has non-NA values on Aug16 at HOURS 8, 9, 10, 11, 12... Aug18 at HOURS 7, 8, 9, 10, 11...Aug19 at HOURS 9, 10, 11, 12, 13. I would like the outcome to be the list of HOURS 9, 10, 11 since those are the non-NA HOURS for all DATES.

Adjusting sum(is.na(x$HRC)) to sum(!is.na(x$HRC)) in Gary's solution did the trick. Thanks everyone!

Comment: I'm asking for advice in terms of coding in R. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example and show what do you expect as result. I am a little bit confusing.

Comment: DATE HOUR HRC
08/15/11 1 NA
08/15/11 2 NA
08/15/11 3 NA
08/15/11 4 NA
08/15/11 5 NA
08/15/11 6 NA
08/15/11 7 20
08/15/11 8 20
08/15/11 9 20
08/15/11 10 20
08/15/11 11 20
08/15/11 12 20
08/15/11 13 20
08/15/11 14 20
08/15/11 15 20
08/15/11 16 20
08/15/11 17 20
08/15/11 18 NA
08/15/11 19 NA
08/15/11 20 NA
08/15/11 21 NA
08/15/11 22 NA
08/15/11 23 NA
08/15/11 24 NA

Comment: data won't fit into comment box

Comment: anyway, the outcome I would like is a list of the hours that have non-NA values for all of the days

Comment: please don't downvote me. I'm trying

Comment: Example: so if DATES are Aug16, Aug18, Aug19, and HRC column has non-NA values on Aug16 at HOURS 8, 9, 10, 11, 12... Aug18 at HOURS 7, 8, 9, 10, 11...Aug19 at HOURS 9, 10, 11, 12, 13. I would like the outcome to be the list of HOURS 9, 10, 11 since those are the non-NA HOURS for all DATES.

Comment: does this make sense?

Comment: Did you test my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
library(plyr)

# assuming your dates are in some date format
d_0 <- as.Date('02-01-2010',format='%m-%d-%Y')

d_1 <- as.Date('02-10-2010',format='%m-%d-%Y')

# assuming your data are in data frame 'dat', get some subset of dates
some_dates <- subset(dat, DATE > d_0 & DATE < d_1)

# count the NAs for each hour
hr_count <- ddply(some_dates, .(HOUR), function(x) sum(!is.na(x$HRC)))
```

Comment: I get "Error: could not find function "ddply""

Comment: Sorry, it is found within the `plyr` package, I have updated the code to reflect this ;-)

Comment: Weird, I then get: "Error in library(plyr) : there is no package called ‘plyr’"

Comment: Ok, so that gives me all the HOURS that have a non-NA value across the days...but I need the HOURS that only have non-NA values for all the days.

Comment: It seems I do not understand your question. Could you provide an example?

Comment: how can i provide an example?

Comment: You can edit your original question and include both a data sample as well as a sample of what output you are looking for. This will help the other users figure out what you want.

Comment: Example: so if DATES are Aug16, Aug18, Aug19, and HRC column has non-NA values on Aug16 at HOURS 8, 9, 10, 11, 12... Aug18 at HOURS 7, 8, 9, 10, 11...Aug19 at HOURS 9, 10, 11, 12, 13. I would like the outcome to be the list of HOURS 9, 10, 11 since those are the non-NA HOURS for all DATES.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. You should include this in your original post too so others will see it. I believe my solution answers this question, let me know how/if it differs.

Comment: Oh, I adjusted sum(is.na(x$HRC)) so that it's sum(!is.na(x$HRC)) and that did the trick for me. THANKS SO MUCH!!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't produce an example, so we are really confused about your question. It is generally constructive to provide a reproducible example. Even if I admit that it is little bit challenging to create example with date types.

```
set.seed(1234)
#generate sequence of 25 days hour by hour
x <- Sys.time() + seq(1,by=60*60,length.out=24*25)
hh <- as.POSIXlt(x)$hour
## generate the data.frame
dat <- data.frame(DATE = as.POSIXct(format(x,"%Y-%m-%d")),
                  HOUR=as.POSIXlt(x)$hour,
                  HRC  = 1:length(x))
## introduce random NA
id <- sample(nrow(dat),10,rep=F)
dat$HRC[id] <- NA
```

Here begins my solution;  it is similar to Gary solution, I am using `plyr` package but with different function.

```
## I choose 2 dates to subset
min.d <- as.POSIXct('2013-03-01')
max.d <- as.POSIXct('2013-03-15')

dat.s <- subset(dat, DATE >=min.d & DATE <= max.d )


res <- ddply(dat.s, .(HOUR),   ## grouping by hour
      function(x){   
        any(is.na(x$HRC))  ## I retuen one HRC at least is NA
      })
```

The result:

```
res[res$V1,]
  HOUR   V1
6     5 TRUE
12   11 TRUE
14   13 TRUE
17   16 TRUE
19   18 TRUE
22   21 TRUE
```

Comment: @user2113323 your are welcom. did you test my solution with your datas?